# How many Async calls we can call in one request in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, asynchronous

I'm writing an app on top of google app engine. Using Java as language.

I'm new to GAE. I want to use URL fetch service for async calls in application.

I'm having few doubts

**1**. How many async calls I can call in one appengine request ?

**2**. What happens if I call more async calls in one request, let's say 50

**3**. What happens these async calls takes more than 1 minute (the appengine request timeout)

**4**. What is default timeout for each async call (I'm assuming it is 60 sec.Is it correct)

Comment: write some code and find out!

Comment: @PaulCollingwood When I tested with 40 parallel async connections it didn't give me any exception, but in few articles some people told limit is 10. Because of confusion I posted question here.

Comment: if the documentation says 10 then stick to 10. As with many things in GAE it's possible to go well over the per second limits for a short time, but it's not something you can rely on. Looking at the documentation (for python) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch it seems you can make 3000 calls a minute then 120,000 if you enable billing. So you have some headroom yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of calls that App Engine can process in general. There are limits (quotas) set for different APIs: e.g. number of Mail API, Task API, URLFetch, etc. calls. Often quotas are different for paying customers, and in most cases you can request to increase a quota if your app requires it. In other words, these quotas do not reflect a technological limitation - they are in place to prevent abuse.

The number of requests that your app can process depends on how many instances you have running, and how fast each call can be processed. You can enable multithreading, so each instance can process multiple calls in parallel.

As for the timeouts, they depend on the [instance type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class) and the type of calls that you are making (Datastore API, Cloud Storage API, URLFetch, etc.)

Comment: ah, I had it entirely the wrong way round in my comment, I thought it was outgoing requests.

Comment: I'm not calling from browser. Calling async calls from appengine application to another appengine application

Comment: @PaulCollingwood: It looks that I misunderstood it! I will update my response.